# MVC5 - How to know if an action input was completely empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action that takes a complex object as an input. I want to be able to populate any of the values with either POST data, or from the query string in a GET request. This works fine.

I also want to provide a default value if no user input was provided, however, this is not working because filter is never null, even if there were no querystring params from a GET request. What happens instead is, MVC just calls the model's default constructor without setting any properties instead of giving me a null.

```
        public ActionResult Index(DataFilterInput filter = null)
        {
            if (filter == null)
                filter = new DataFilterInput { Top = 100 };
            var model = new IndexModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

How can I know whether I should be defaulting the values in the absence of user input (I do not want to go into the Request query string or form collections)?

Comment: check model state and look into data attributes

Comment: @Nkosi, can you please provide a little bit more detail and submit this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Did you try `[DefaultValue(null)]` attribute in front of the parameter declaration instead of `= null`? I wonder if that would change the behavior.

Comment: that did not work sedat

Answer (score 0):

to provide a default value for your object this sample would work

```
public class SearchModel
{
  public bool IsMarried{ get; set; }


public SearchModel()
  { 
    IsMarried= true;
  }
}
```

and if you want to validate the model

```
 public ActionResult Index(DataFilterInput filter = null)
        {
         if (!ModelState.Isvalied)
                filter = new DataFilterInput { Top = 100 };
            var model = new IndexModel();
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: What if I am using this view model multiple places and I want different defaults in different actions? The issue with this answer is that it applies to anyone who uses the default constructor

Comment: you should create a model and customize your view model with the default constructor in each time you use it as an object.

Comment: There can only be one default constructor

Comment: i mean in ViewModel you can create as many as you want ViewModel and in each time use the default constructor of the ViewModel

Comment: @AlameerAshraf you want to create the default if the modelstate is false not true. and you need to explain how to use the data attributes in validating the state of the model.

Comment: There is no invalid state of the model. Any value is valid, I just need to know if no input was provided so that I can supply defaults

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer so you saying a model with Top=0 is a valid model?

Comment: yes, because they can use different parameters that make Top irrelevant

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer ok understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can decare top `nullable`

```
public int? Top {get;set;}
```

So when no top value is provided it will be `null` by default and you can check it by using `==null` or  `HasValue` like this

```
public ActionResult Index(DataFilterInput filter ) 
  { 
    if (!filter.Top.HasValue ) 
        filter = new DataFilterInput { Top = 100 }; 
    var model = new IndexModel(); 
    return View(model);
   }
```

Comment: Top already is nullable. That is a valid state because someone could request info about a specific entity instead of the top whatever

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer then you should `nullable` all the properties which are valid and check condition as `filter.Top.HasValue && filter.property1.HasValue  && filter.property2.HasValue`

Comment: That is not a maintainable solution.